# Lucene.Net Query Building

Tags: c#, search, lucene.net

I'm trying to build a BooleanQuery with Lucene.Net and running into problems.

I have a field within my index called "Category Types".

In this field i have stored "pipe" separated categories like below :-

"Doh Archive|Far Archive|Soh Archive".

I want to build a method where I will pass in one of these categories and i will filter the index to those documents that contain that category.

I've started to build a BooleanQuery, and added the following TermQuery to it :-

```
BooleanQuery MasterQuery = new BooleanQuery(true);

Query categoryQuery = new TermQuery(new Term ("CategoryTypes", "Doh Archive"));

MasterQuery.Add(categoryQuery , Occur.MUST);

TopDocs results = searcher.Search(MasterQuery, null, 100);
```

The problem is, I'm not getting any results, theres over 24,000 entries in the Index, and i'm using Luke4ALL to ensure that what im trying to search for exists.

The Idea is that i will build onto this MasterQuery with more Queries, but i'm stumped at the first hurdle.

Can Anyone Help?

Comment: `TermQuery` requires *exact match*.

Comment: So which Query type should i use in this instance?

Comment: You can use *QueryParser*, but it still depends on how you index that field. I would index the same field with 3 differnet values, instead of using pipe-separated single filed.

Comment: Ive just set it up as a stored field and analyzed?

Comment: ok , thanks, I was just trying to save on size? is what i'm doing not best practice?

Comment: Depending on the analyzer you used, the token in index may be a single one `Doh Archive|Far Archive|Soh Archive`, or maybe 4 tokens like  `Doh` `Archive` `Far` `Soh`. Both ways wouldn't work for TermQuery. Not best practice. Not event correct as you see.